# BlazeDS+ActiveMQ: non-graceful disconnection of Flex client from a durable topic does not remove it from ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-flex, activemq-classic, blazeds

I'm trying to make a Flex-based desktop application consume messages from an ActiveMQ topic with a durable subscription, using the JMS bridge of BlazeDS. The basic scenario is as follows:

1. Messages are produced by other producers in the topic to which the Flex client is subscribed.
2. The Flex client may go offline from time to time, but it must receive all the messages it has missed while being offline when it connects to BlazeDS again. (Of course the Flex client connects with the same client ID every time).
3. It can *not* be guaranteed that the Flex client is shut down gracefully.

Everything works fine if I explicitly disconnect my consumer on the Flex side by calling `disconnect()` - I do it in the exit handler of the application. However, due to #3 above, it is not guaranteed that `disconnect()` is called all the time. When the Flex client shuts down without calling `disconnect()`, it seems that the subscription of the "proxy JMS client" that BlazeDS creates and associates to the Flex client stays active towards ActiveMQ, so ActiveMQ still thinks that the client is logged in. When the Flex app starts up the next time, it is unable to log in to BlazeDS because ActiveMQ refuses its subscription, claiming that the client ID is already taken. Why is it so and what can I do here to ensure that BlazeDS makes the "proxy JMS client" offline in ActiveMQ when its real Flex counterpart terminates unexpectedly?

**More detailed information**: some debugging revealed that:

1. BlazeDS becomes aware of the termination of the Flex client because it prints a few exceptions to the console when in debug mode. The messages are as follows:

   ```
   [BlazeDS]23:18:13.688 [WARN] Endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf' is closing the streaming connection to FlexClient with id '71E6466F-D91F-201C-F60A-A6CB52F95D9F' because endpoint encountered a socket write error, possibly due to an unresponsive FlexClient.
   ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:319)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:542)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:279)
       at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.handleFlexClientStreamingOpenRequest(BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.java:818)
       at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.serviceStreamingRequest(BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.java:1055)
       at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseStreamingHTTPEndpoint.java:460)
       at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java:353)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:737)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:434)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:299)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:963)
       at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:314)
       ... 20 more

   [BlazeDS]23:18:13.689 [DEBUG] Streaming thread 'http-8400-1' for endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf' is releasing connection and returning to the request handler pool.
   [BlazeDS]23:18:13.689 [INFO] Number of streaming clients for FlexSession with id '5BC5E8D604A361BCA673B05AC624CCC1' is 0.
   [BlazeDS]23:18:13.689 [DEBUG] Number of streaming clients for endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf' is 0.
   ```

   At this stage, the subscriptions are still shown on the ActiveMQ web admin interface as being active.
2. Killing BlazeDS (more precisely, the Tomcat server that hosts it) with `kill -9` from the console makes ActiveMQ realize immediately that the "proxy JMS client" is gone and it becomes offline on the ActiveMQ web admin interface. This made me conclude that BlazeDS is keeping the proxy JMS client alive explicitly since `kill -9` gives no chance to BlazeDS to unsubscribe the client but it still becomes offline in ActiveMQ.

So, the question once again: What can I do here to ensure that BlazeDS makes the "proxy JMS client" offline in ActiveMQ when its real Flex counterpart terminates unexpectedly? Is this a bug in BlazeDS or am I just missing some hidden configuration setting that would make it work?

Version information: BlazeDS 4.0, ActiveMQ 5.5.0, both freshly downloaded today. I'm using the Tomcat server in the BlazeDS turnkey but ActiveMQ is installed separately because the BlazeDS turnkey ships with ActiveMQ 4.1.1 only. By the way, that version of ActiveMQ has the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901502/activemq-does-not-stop-subscription-when-flex-client-disconnects . The issue is similar in my case, but I thought it deserves a separate question as the other topic does not mention durable subscriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no way for BlazeDS to detect that your Flex client was shutdown, you will have to implement your own mechanism - my suggestion is to use a heart beat implemented with messaging. If no message is received from the client after a time interval you can assume that the Flex client is gone and do the disconnect (or you can use the session timeout mechanism on the server, and do the disconnect on session expire).

What you have seen (the exception caught when the streaming channel is closed) is not enough to say 100% sure that the Flex client is gone. The streaming is implemented using an HTTP connection kept open forever (used to send server messages) and periodic HTTP post calls (initiated by the client to send messages). In some networks the firewall can decide to kill the HTTP connection after a couple of seconds and you will receive the same error like the one you posted. However, it does not mean that the Flex client is killed - the Flex client can use a fallback strategy and switch to short/long polling in this case. Actually it would be a bug if BlazeDS will automatically do the JMS disconnect in this case.

Comment: Thanks for dropping by - I really appreciate your answer. However, there's one thing I don't understand here. I see why BlazeDS should not unsubscribe the proxy client from the topic in JMS entirely, but I don't understand why can't it simply make it an "offline durable client" which would allow the Flex client to reconnect later. Even if the Flex client is still alive, it wouldn't hurt to make it offline briefly until the fallback connection is established, right?

Comment: I think that is a viable option, but using streaming for messaging is a particular case..polling seems to be a safer option. I mean as if I would be the BlazeDS product manager I wouldn't care too much about that. The most important thing is that you can achieve you desired result with what you already have in the product, in my opinion. However there are more options: post a request on Jira for that, or modify the BlazeDS code by yourself (the code is opensource and is not hard to understand).